# how to build JDT core using eclipse, or any IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I am interested in understanding how JDT core works, so I tried to create a project in Eclipse to build (and possibly debug) JDT core. But after following the instructions at http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core_Committer_FAQ and http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Git_Workflows, I have 12 projects in my Eclipse workspace,

[image]

with 8094 errors complaining about various symbols cannot be resolved.

[image]

The unresolved symbols are due to missing classes, and a quick search shows the those java files are in the project directories. I guess this is because I didn't config all the projects correctly. I will try to describe in more detail what I did so far and the problems I have now. But for now, could someone please direct me to some information/tutorial about how to do this? I spent already much time searching for such info, but so far no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: The picture indicates that the org.eclipse.jdt.core project has a build path problem. What is it? Could be lack of a compatible JRE or such? This should be seen as the root cause behind most/all other problems.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I also feel the problem is with build paths, but couldn't figure out the exact reason. The instructions from the above-mentioned two pages say nothing about other configurations of the projects other than importing them from the Git repositories. 

I don't think the problem is about missing a compatible JRE or anything similar.

Comment: If you still have that workspace, the Problems view should have the necessary information, if only you manage to isolate the root cause among those thousands of errors. First step to narrow down: in the view menu of the Problems view, select "Show > Errors/Warnings on project", now by selecting org.eclipse.jdt.core you focus on errors of this project alone. In that list sort by the "Type" column, which should lead you to the underlying "Build Path Problem". The existence of such problem is shown by the big red bang on the project.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann In project org.eclipse.jdt.core, I can see one problem of type `Plug-in problem` and several others of `Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping problem`. The plug-in problem is within 'plugin.xml' (line 275) because of 'Unkown extension point: org.eclipse.ui.trace.traceComponents'. That's strange.

Comment: M2e lifecycle mapping issues should be harmless, though JDT developers typically don't use m2e. poms are provided just for automated builds. In the IDE they add nothing.

Comment: Is the plugin `org.eclipse.ui.trace` missing from your eclipse installation?? Or from your target platform, if you have defined one? The extension point exists since version 1.0 of that plugin. Maybe you should look at `MANIFEST.MF` and see if any dependency problems are reported here? And really no problem classified as `Build Path Problem`?

Comment: I changed the target platform from an integration build to the RCP edition and the 'plug-in' problem is gone now. There is no `Build Path Problem`. There are however several problems about `Bundle 'org.eclipse.test.performance' cannot be resolved` in several MANIFEST.MF files.

Comment: `org.eclipse.test.performance` is mentioned in the FAQ (wiki) under "Where is the JDT/Core code?" It's from git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.git

Answer (score 1):

A alternative, new way to guide you through (aka "automate") setting up a JDT workspace is using the **eclipse installer** (aka "Oomph"), as documented in https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Code_Setup_Using_Oomph.

This may or may not detect / avoid the problems resulting from the manual setup.

Comment: Thanks, Oomph really makes setting up the JDT workspace very easy.